# updating from non-instance in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I am trying to figure out how to best update a row using a non-instance object. The use case is (I suppose) very common. Basically, I have a save API method:

```
function save(req, res, next) {
    var instance = req.body;
    var promise;

    if (instance[this.pkeyProperty]) {
        promise = this.model.update(instance, {
            [this.pkeyProperty]: instance[this.pkeyProperty],
            returning: true
        })
        .then((affectedCount, affectedRows) => affectedRows[0])
    }
    else {
        promise = this.model.create(instance);
    }

    promise
        .then((instance) => res.ok(instance))
        .catch(err => res.serverError(err));
}
```

wondering if this is an appropriate way to insertOrUpdate (I saw the upsert method, however I don't want to use it because I want my calls to return the newly created instance without having to find them after the insert/update).

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would use [`findOrCreate` method](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findorcreateoptions-promiseinstance-created)

```
function save(req, res, next) {
    var instance = req.body;

    this.model.findOrCreate( { 
        where : { [this.pKeyProperty] : instance[this.pKeyProperty] },
        defaults : instance
    }).spread( (result, created) => {
       return created ? result : result.update(instance) 
    }).then( instance => {
       res.ok( instance );
    }).catch( err => res.serverError(err) );
}
```

It will find or create the new instance and return it.

Comment: Yes, but what about an update? I need it to create or update in the db. Looks like you code will only create...

Comment: Ahh my bad will modify.

Comment: But doesn't your code take two queries to update an instance. What is wrong with mine (which I believe only makes one query).

Comment: Yep... Fair point. I guess your method makes less queries. Actually my way of doing the API end-points is to use `PUT` for updates & `POST` for creating an entity, so I've never had your situation. Nevertheless, sorry for the noise.